Blender plugin importing UVs Wrong - Marvel Guardians of the Galaxy model import plugin (*.pc_prim)
I recently started import Marvel GotG models but whenever I import (Blender 2.9 - 3.3.5 or any other version) the model looks perfect but the UV is wrong. Only 1 UVMAP

bl_info = {
    "name": "Guardians of the Galaxy PC (*.pc_prim)",
    "description": "Import Guardians of the Galaxy Models",
    "author": "kboykboy, Irastris",
    "category": "Import",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 90, 0),
}

from math import log2
from struct import unpack

import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty
from bpy.types import Operator, Panel
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper

def unpackShort(prim):
    return unpack("<H", prim.read(2))[0]

def unpackLong(prim):
    return unpack("<I", prim.read(4))[0]

def unpackLongLong(prim):
    return unpack("<Q", prim.read(8))[0]

def unpackFloat(prim):
    return unpack("<f", prim.read(4))[0]

class GOTG_OT_ImportModel(Operator, ImportHelper):
    bl_label = "Import PRIM"
    bl_idname = "gotg.import_model"
    
    import_lods: BoolProperty(name="Import LODs", description="Whether or not to import all LODs or only LOD 0.", default=False)
    
    def execute(self, context):
        with open(self.filepath, "rb") as prim:
            headerLength = 12
            prim.seek(92)
            meshCount = unpackLong(prim)
            
            for n in range(meshCount):
                loc = prim.tell()
                meshLOD = int(log2(unpackLong(prim)))
                meshNum = unpackLong(prim)
                
                if meshLOD > 0:
                    if not self.import_lods:
                        prim.seek(loc+296)
                        continue
                
                prim.seek(64, 1)
                uScale, vScale, uOffset, vOffset = [unpackFloat(prim) for _ in range(4)]
                vertnum = unpackShort(prim)
                prim.seek(6, 1)
                vertloc = unpackLongLong(prim) + headerLength + 4
                prim.seek(8, 1)
                faceloc = unpackLongLong(prim) + headerLength + 4
                facenum = int(unpackLong(prim) / 3)
                prim.seek(vertloc + 6)
                if unpackShort(prim) == 15360:
                    vformat = "half"
                    FVF = 8
                else:
                    vformat = "float"
                    FVF = 12
                prim.seek(faceloc)
                faces = []
                for n in range(facenum):
                    index1, index2, index3 = [unpackShort(prim) for _ in range(3)]
                    faces.append([index1, index2, index3])
                prim.seek(vertloc)
                verts = []
                if vformat == "float":
                    for n in range(vertnum):
                        x, y, z = [unpack("<f", prim.read(4))[0] for _ in range(3)]
                        prim.seek(FVF - 12, 1)
                        verts.append([x, y, z])
                if vformat == "half":
                    for n in range(vertnum):
                        x, y, z = [unpack("<e", prim.read(2))[0] for _ in range(3)]
                        prim.seek(FVF - 6, 1)
                        verts.append([x, y, z])
                prim.seek(vertnum * 24, 1)
                uvloc = prim.tell()
                uvs = []
                for n in range(len(verts)):
                    x, y = [unpack("<h", prim.read(2))[0] for _ in range(2)]
                    x = ((x / 32768.0) * uScale) + uOffset
                    y = ((y / 32768.0) * vScale) + vOffset
                    uvs.append([x, y])
                
                mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(f"Mesh{meshNum}-LOD{meshLOD}")
                obj = bpy.data.objects.new(mesh.name, mesh)
                bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj)
                mesh.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
                me = obj.data
                if uvs != 0:
                    uvlayer = me.uv_layers.new()
                    me.uv_layers.active = uvlayer
                    num = 0
                    for face in me.polygons:
                        for vert_idx, loop_idx in zip(face.vertices, face.loop_indices):
                            uv = uvs[vert_idx]
                            uvlayer.data[loop_idx].uv = (uv[0], uv[1])
                            num = num + 1
                
                print(f"{obj.name} {uvloc}")
                
                prim.seek(loc+296)
        
        return{'FINISHED'}

classes = (
    GOTG_OT_ImportModel,
)

def menu_import_draw(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(GOTG_OT_ImportModel.bl_idname, text="Guardians of the Galaxy (.prim)")

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_import.append(menu_import_draw)
    
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_import.remove(menu_import_draw)

if __name__=="__main__":
    register()



Is this a script you wrote or is this an addon you got from a third party? If it's the former then are you asking for us to help debug your script? It would be helpful to see the UVs in whatever application you're importing it from as well. Nothing seems too off looking at the script to import the UVs, but we can't really tell much beyond that as you're working with some custom binary struct parser. It could be that the 3rd party app is messing up the UVs, could be the binary it's written in is off, could be your script. No way we can tell.
